# Resistive Divider

Tags: analog

[image]

[image]

In a nutshell, the book says

[image]

However, I don't see how that's true. If I re-draw that resistive sensing part as follows:

[image]

Surely, isn't it just

[image]

**Why do I have a minus instead of a +?**

EDIT: I just realised by using KCL at Vout node that the book is correct. For som reason, I thought the usual voltage division equation where the bottom node is ground would apply here too.

Comment: The usual voltage divider equation does apply, but which voltage will you get with it?

Comment: If \$V_{out1} = V\_{out2}\$, would \$V_{out,CM} = 0\$? ... apply Ohm's law!

Comment: @TemeV Vout_CM ?

Comment: Update: Just figured out my mistake. The Vout_CM I'm getting in my equation is not in reference to ground. It's Vout_CM - Vout2, bringing Vout2 to the other side, get's me the correct equation. @TemeV Thanks

Comment: @Alfro: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks. I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

is not correct. The Vout,CM here is not in reference to ground, it is a reference to Vout2. This is in-fact calculating Vout,CM - Vout2. If you bring the Vout2 across, you get the correct answer:
[image]

Comment: Is this an alternative answer to your answer of 12 hours previously? If not then move it into an update of the previous answer. Remember you're on a Q&A site, not a forum. Answers float up and down by user votes and user sorting preference. See the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Yes, it's an alternate answer